# Find then Sum with IMongoCollection

Tags: c#, mongodb-.net-driver

I am writing an api to sum a column called ViewCount from collection. At the moment, my code is something like this:

```
 var filter = Builders<Post>.Filter.Eq(u => u.IsDelete, query.Param.IsDelete);

 IMongoCollection<Post> _posts;
 var postViewCount = _posts.Find(filter).ToList().Select(a =>a.ViewCount).Sum();
```

Result is ok with correct summation but performance is getting slow a lots with only 20k records (about 6s for simple call). If I use like this, it will be very faster (just 200ms) but I cannot put filter in here:

```
 var filter = Builders<Post>.Filter.Eq(u => u.IsDelete, query.Param.IsDelete);

 IMongoCollection<Post> _posts;
 var postViewCount = _posts.AsQueryable().Sum(x => x.ViewCount);
```

So my question is how can I handle this case? Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.Where()`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_Linq_MongoQueryable_Where__1.htm). After calling `.AsQueryable()` you get [`IQueryable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iqueryable-1?view=netcore-3.1), so you have all LINQ funtionality available. :)

```
_posts.AsQueryable().Where(filter).Sum(x => x.ViewCount);
```

Comment: Sorry but my filter is type Builders from MongoDB driver. So I cannot put filter in WHERE clause like this :(

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Agg feature, you will get a faster query.

Good luck with!

```
var aggregate = new BsonDocument
{
  { "Count", new BsonDocument("$sum", 1) }
};
_posts.Aggregate().Match(filter).Group(aggregate);
```